# Azure Datafactory Global parameter conflict while using terraform IAC and ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am new to terraform, I have created datafactory  and Logic Apps (standard) using terraform in TEST environment and code deployment using ARM template and Azure Devops CICD .  after we have commit code we have deploy the code to DEV environment using azure CICD. later when i check the terraform plan, i could see terraform complain about ADF global parameter and Logic app connection need to update in terraform state file, I just confused if i update the terraform state file with global parameter and office365 connection details for logicapp , how can i deploy to further environment say PROD without code deployment . while creating the infrastructure all the ADF global parameter will be come to ADF right? but i don't want this, i want a only ADF and Logicapp resources without Global Parameters and office365 connection in further environment.

[image]

Can you please help how can i achieve this problem

Comment: That terraform plan is for dev environment right? How did you create and put in the global parameters for dev env (through terraform or ADF UI)?

Comment: I have created Dev environment manually not through terraform and deploy the code Through ARM deployment using Azure Devops CICD but for TEST env I have created all Azure infra using Terraform and Deploy the code using ARM template using Azure DevOps CICD

Comment: please provide the info in the image in text format @gsrao

Comment: Ok I’m confused now. From your question I thought you only have DEV and PROD environments, but now there’s TEST env too? Can you provide these information in your question to clarify it:
1. List of environments you have and how you created it (terraform or manual). And 2. On which environment are you getting the error

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , I have DEV and Test Environment for now  but in future i will create Prod, DEV i have create manually through Azure Portal UI and for TEST Infra i have created using Terraform and Azure CICD and for code deployment   ADF and Logic app i have used ARM template using Azure Devops CICD. I am getting this issue with Test environment when I want to change few configuration changes I have run terraform plan where i am getting Global parameter not in sync with current environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response @VinayB - Briefly the issue is, I have TEST Datafactory environment which i created using terraform and I was deployed  ADF pipeline include Global parameter from GIT to Test environment LIVE  using Azure Devops CICD with ARM Template till now it is good. But when i trying to add one more resources to Terraform file, Since terraform not aware of ADF global parameter state which we deployed from ARM deployment, terraform plan saying it will overwrite the existing Global parameter with null. in case if i add the global parameter in TF file it will be problem in PROD env.